# Get user's location using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using below piece of code to get user's location however, it does not return location

```
FB.api('/me?fields=picture,location', function(res) {
    console.log(res); // no location
});
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong and how can I get user location?

**UPDATE**

With [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Clocation%2Chometown%2Cpicture&version=v2.8), it does give user location but with above code it does not.

**UPDATE 2**

Any idea how can I get location of user using Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Comment: What happens when you use the `locations` call as per the [Facebook Graph API - user/locations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/locations) (i know it says removed, but humor me :) )

Comment: This [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Clocation%2Chometown&version=v2.8) might help you troubleshoot.  Pop you app token in, or click the [Get Token] and select the permissions you wish, then test and see if it gives the response you wish (ideally the location). I seen somewhere else that it asks for specific fields now (city, etc) instead of just 'location'. (Trying to find that link for you)

Comment: With token it seems to be working however, how can I use this token in my code above?

Comment: The token is sent during `FB.init()` -- i believe.  I haven't worked much with the FB sdk :S

Comment: Still waiting for the solution....

Comment: Anyone who can help me with this? I am still waiting for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works in the API Explorer, but not in your App, there can only be one reason: You did not authorize with the `user_location` permission. In the API Explorer, you can just select it in a popup. In your code, you have to specifically ask for it with `FB.login`:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app
        FB.api('/me?fields=picture,location', function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}, {scope: 'user_location', return_scopes: true});
```

Bigger example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

**Make sure you try this as user with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester), or it will not even ask for the permission**. If you want to go public, you need to go through the review process first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

I have added the `return_scopes` parameter and a `console.log` at the beginning of the first callback, debug the response in the chrome dev tools and make sure it includes the `user_location` permission.

Btw, you get an Access Token in the response too, use the Debugger to check for the authorized permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am working on this only for my dev environment. That means I am not going to  publish it publicly. It seems like above solution with return_scopes still not returning user location.

Comment: then you did not authorize the permission. make sure you add it to the scope parameter and make sure you get asked for it in the authorization process. make sure you are using a user with a role in the app, that´s the most important thing. you should see a warning that the permission needs to get reviewed if you try the code as app admin.

Comment: i am 99% sure it is a permission issue, as it works in the api explorer.

Comment: I am already an admin after checking in roles. Still not getting location.

Comment: so do you get asked for the permission or not? that´s a very important question.

Comment: btw, i have added a paragraph about the token debugger. use it to debug your token after login.

Comment: I am not asked for permissions at all during login process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132216/discussion-between-2619-and-luschn).